# Maximum Messages can process into message-driven (public-subscribe) of Spring Reactive (Mono/WebFlux)

Tags: spring, reactive

Spring 5 focus on reactive programming which base on event handling architecture. In case we want to process 1M messages parallel. How we override default configuration and avoid limitation maximum public-subscribe messages  of Push request Event, Trigger Callback, Event Loop, Register callback and push operation completed events

Comment: On a Raspberry Pi, or on a 32-core high-end server? Doing what? This question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Hi @JBNizet, does message message-driven have limitation? when we push more than 1M messages, how they process. Event Loop base on Threading, if we create a lot of pools so it will keep resource and our application will be slow down. need your help to share me your experience?